# Time dependent Email alert with CC, BCC

Tags: email, workflow

I need to send out email alerts on specific days based on the value of a date field. Infact two emails- one when the date approaches and other 10 days later. Now a time based workflow would have easily worked. But the requirement also has cc and bcc fields in the email template. How can i incorporate these features while sending email through workflow?
If not what is the way around.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, this is not possible using a Workflow Email Alert Action.

Please check this link to vote for https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrEkAAK

Workaround would be to achieve this via Process Builder or Apex.

Comment: not sure how Process Builder helps as it references Email Alerts and email alerts cant' specify cc or bcc.